# aspx .net only processing first postback until reload project in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2019, postback

I'm working on an old aspx site in .NET Framework 4.0, and using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.4.

The Developer Web Server settings are:

- Always Start when Debugging: False
- Anonymous Authentication: Enabled
- Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic
- SSL Enabled: False

When I start the application it loads fine. I navigate to a form. I submit the form. The data posts correctly. I submit the same form, and nothing posts. Nor does any other form post. And when clicking any button that is hooked up to a postback, it is not processed as a postback. If I reload the project by selecting File>Open>Website>[Project Directory] I can restart it and again make only one successful postback.

I pulled the code from the production site which is working fine. So I'm sure it has to do with my specific dev instance of the application running in Visual Studio.

Comment: It may be that there is a problem with the code related to the postback. Can you remove the private information and paste the related code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT since I copied working code from production, I'm not sure what code is suspect. I considered sharing a stripped down version of the web.config, or maybe a specific section of it. Would that help?